Why is there more matter than antimatter in the universe?
Even if we assume that the electron, due to its negative charge, is an antimatter particle, why did matter as we know it form from protons, neutrons, and electrons, and not from antiprotons, antineutrons, and positrons?

Here is one contender for the reason - Can leptogenesis explain why there's something instead of nothing?


The electron is not classified as an antimatter particle. Its charge is irrelevant to that classification.
The names matter and antimatter can be freely switched, so there is no particular reason why we have protons instead of antiprotons in terms of categorization. We just named the dominant type of matter as matter, and the other type as antimatter. Equivalently, we could have defined the electron charge as positive and the proton charge as negative. The only important thing is that they are opposite.
It is unclear why exactly there is an imbalance between the amount of matter and antimatter in the universe, as they appear at first glance to be made in equal amounts across symmetric processes. Several hypotheses are being investigated. See e.g. this Wikipedia article.


Wow. -4 downvotes.
I think you have a point. The opening statement, "if we assume that the electron, due to its negative charge, is an antimatter particle" is going to trigger a lot of "swipe left"s if you know what I mean. It's just so wrong! [queue Vsauce ( https://www.youtube.com/shorts/3cMJE3lMRL4 ) music]:
Or is it?
First, let's give history it's due respect: stuff is made from protons and electrons (with neutrons along for the ride), so we called that stuff "matter", long before quantum field theory.
Then, in 1928, Paul Dirac wrote down his eponymous equation with "negative energy" solutions, followed by Carl Andersen's 1932 discovery of the positron on Mt Wilson in the Los Angeles National Forest, and the division of particles into matter and anti-matter was inevitable.
Suppose, instead, we had the Standard Model given to us by supernatural means...tablets, bushes, ghosts of PRL past/present/future, whatever...and we had to make a power point presentation describing it.
Here's what I would do: I would have matter and conjugate matter.
Why not anti-matter? Well further investigation of the Dirac equation shows that Lorentz symmetry requires electrons come in a four component package, with an arbitrary "upper" spin-doublet with lepton number $L=+1$ (by definition) and charge $Q=\pm 1$ and a conjugate lower spin-doublet with $L=-1$ and $Q=\mp 1$.
So the 2 positron solutions are more like conjugates to the 2 electron solutions, imho. Nevertheless, that $e^++e^- \rightarrow {\rm energy}$  really promotes the "anti" prefix. idk. I will use "conjugate" to avoid confusion.
So our $SM2.0$ (Standard Model, version 2.0) would now build from two fundamental doublets:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
u\\ d
\end{array}\right),\ \ 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
e^+\\ \nu_e
\end{array}\right)
$$
and likewise for heavier generations. (Note that neutrino here is what we now call an anti neutrino).
This has a nice symmetry. Matter comes in baryon or lepton doublets, where the "top" entry has $+1$ more unit of charge than the bottom entry.
Since they're all spin $\frac 1 2$ particles, they have conjugates:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
\bar u\\ \bar d
\end{array}\right),\ \ 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
e^-\\ \bar{\nu}_e
\end{array}\right)
$$
which all have the signs of electric charge, color charge, baryon number, and lepton number reversed (I'm leaving out weak charges....for now).
Aside: You will often hear popular sci media say there are 2 kinds of electric charge and 3 kinds of color charge, which is confusing. There is one kind of electric charge that comes in $+$, and its conjugate: $-$, the same way $(r, g, b)$ has its conjugates $(\bar r, \bar g, \bar b)$ Note: thanks to human vision, the conjugate color charges can be whimsically called cyan, magenta and yellow.
The beta-decay amplitude is then captured in the diagram (which I can't draw):
$$ d + \bar u \rightarrow W^- \rightarrow e^- + \nu_e $$
taking a ($Q=-1$, $B=0$, $L=0$) initial state to a ($Q=-1$, $B=0$, $L=0$) final state.
Proton decay (from GUTs):
$$ p^+ \rightarrow e^+ + \pi^0 $$
now conserves $B+L$, converting baryons into leptons, which I find "nicer".
Your question about baryogengesis (which is a major area of research and is equivalent to asking "Identify dark matter"--a bit too much for this site) is no longer "Where is all the antimatter", it's why does the universe have:
$$ B >0, L < 0 $$
since matter is made from protons (baryons) and electrons (conjugate-leptons).
Proton decay then initiates the chain:
$$ ^1{\rm H} \rightarrow p + e^- $$
$$ p \rightarrow e^+ + \pi^0 $$
$$\pi^0 \rightarrow 2\gamma $$
$$ e^+ + e^- \rightarrow 2\gamma $$
or:
$$ ^1{\rm H} \rightarrow 4\gamma $$
So we start with $B+L=0$, something drives $B$ ($L$) positive (negative), the universe happens, and over eons, we return to that state.
Nevertheless, it's too late to adopt this convention.
